# Can I setup XBMC to automatically detect media without saving them into specific directories?

Tags: htpc, kodi, boxee

I've recently upgraded an old HTPC box and in the process switched from the Boxee Windows app to the latest version of XBMC (12.3). I've found the process to be a really mixed bag. While Boxee hadn't been updated in several years it would still do a fairly decent job of automatically recognizing tv and movies.

I've found XBMC's process of moving each type of file into it's own directory to be really cumbersome, especially given that Boxee would do that heavy lifting for me.

Is there any combination of plugins or settings that will let XBMC behave in a similar manner? I'd simply like to dump all my media into a single folder, let XBMC detect what type of content it is, and let me correct it when XBMC gets it wrong.

Comment: How do you organize your files for Boxee? Perhaps a media manager like [Media Browser 3](http://mediabrowser3.com/) might be a solution for managing the files. MB3 has plugins that allows you to interact with it within XBMC.

Comment: It wasn't organized :). TV and Movies were simply dumped into a single directory. I then added that directory as a media library to Boxee and it did the rest.

Comment: I'm surprise Boxee was able to sort it all. The least I would do is to separate TV and Movie folders. Either way give Media Browser or Plex a look.

Comment: Do either one detect the media on their own, or is it a similar process to XBMC?

Comment: XBMC, Boxee, Media Browser and Plex alls scrape information from online or local sources (.nfos). They have different engine for that process, that's why you get different results. I say try both of them, and see which one fits your needs better.